# Wordpress Admin of Huge Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, multisite

I might have a rare use case for Wordpress Multisite.  Our company creates wordpress websites for users, and when we build the website we put it on a single Wordpress Multisite install.  We have Wordpress admin users that are made admins of all the sites.  We are now up to over 3500 sites on the one Wordpress instance.  I can no longer login as as an admin due to hitting a 504 page and timing out.

I tried increasing memory size and a number of other changes in the environment but the login pages keeps timing out no matter what I do.  I disabled all plugins to test and it still times out.  I seem to be hitting a memory limit in the db query.

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1972
```

I created a test admin user that only connects to a single site and it logs in fine.  Also when not logged in the sites are very quick.

My guess is since this admin is connected to all 3500ish sites a query is being made against all tables at login.  Or at least too many.

I am on PHP 7.4 and Wordpress 5.2.14.

Does anyone know if there is a way to configure Wordpress to do a better job of scoping context down to just the website I am logging in to?  I am sort of assuming that is the issue.  Or maybe I need to upgrade Wordpress to a later version that handles for that.  Or maybe I am not a use case they built multisite for (admin for all the sites).  I know there are installs with multiple times more sites than ours so I am not concerned with the total number on the single install.

Maybe I am just stuck and if so I can come up with another way to admin sites, but seeing all of them is helpful.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory limit in your WP config file?

Comment: You might be a candidate for [multi-network](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/), which is a network of multi-sites, and supported natively by WordPress. Unfortunately there's not a lot of documentation out there for this. Otherwise, do you have a memory-based cache like Redis or Memached available? That might relieve some pressure.

Comment: Thanks guys yes I increased the memory in multiple places. WP config file, php config, even one answer I found told me to try to vhost file.  None of those worked.  I think I have a solution but testing this morning and will respond if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution after 2 days or work.

In case anyone else runs into a similar issue I will let you know what worked for me to solve this problem.  I am by no means a Wordpress expert which is probably why I ran into this issue in the first place.  Also if someone has a better answer or way of explaining this please feel free to correct me.

To clarify I was using a Super Admin which is only available in Wordpress Multisite.  Basically he/she can make any edits to plugins, themes, users, etc for the whole multisite.

When we created a new blog we were duplicating the same base blog.  This had all the pages and settings that new blog needed to work in our system.  This included making the Super Admin the explicit admin for that new blog.  Which we didn't need to do.  The Super Admin can do everything needed on the new blog without making him/her an explicit admin of the blog.

Once I created a new Super Admin of the Multisite there was no timeout in fact logging into any blog was amazingly fast.  To be 100% honest I am still not sure the specific code that timed out, but I am assuming Wordpress does some sort of look up for all Blogs a user is an admin of on login.  And for the Super Admin this was all the blogs.